# Elixir HTTPoisin.get avoid dedup in response data

Tags: duplicates, elixir, httpoison

I am making call to HTTP Rest API in elixir

```
url = "http://localhost:8080/getScoreData"
   case HTTPoison.get(url) do
     {:ok, %{status_code: 200, body: body}} ->
       Logger.info("body is #{inspect(body)}")
       overall_score = Jason.decode!(body, as: [%OverallScore{}])
       {:ok, overall_score}
   end
```

which in the web browser returns

```
{
      "avgPass": 85.55,
      "avgFail": 14.45,
      "totalStudents": 80.0,
      "myScoreSchema": [
        {
          "average": 80.0,
          "count": 8.0,
          "percent": 80.0,
          "name": "John"
        },
        {
          "average": 0.0,
          "count": 0.0,
          "percent": 0.0,
          "name": "Cena"
        },
        {
          "average": 0.0,
          "count": 0.0,
          "percent": 0.0,
          "name": "Sunny"
        },
        {
          "average": 0.0,
          "count": 0.0,
          "percent": 0.0,
          "name": "Michael"
        }
      ]
    }
```

but the log as of the line `Logger.info("body is #{inspect(body)}")` from above code [dedups](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#dedup/1)
the data and returns below data instead

```
{
      "avgPass": 85.55,
      "avgFail": 14.45,
      "totalStudents": 80.0,
      "myScoreSchema": [
        {
          "average": 80.0,
          "count": 8.0,
          "percent": 80.0,
          "name": "John"
        },
        {
          "average": 0.0,
          "count": 0.0,
          "percent": 0.0,
          "name": "Cena Sunny Michael"
        }
      ]
    }
```

Even though this is a smart feature but I don't want this dedup feature. How to avoid the dedup.

Comment: Could you try `HTTPoison.get! "http://localhost:8080/getScoreData"` in `iex` and post what you get back? It’s extremely unlikely `HTTPoison` would deduplicate data.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin: Yes, tried that and it still deduplicate data

Comment: Could you try `curl http://localhost:8080/getScoreData` in terminal?

Comment: Which version of `httpoison` are you using?

Comment: @z5ottu: httpoison verion 1.5.1

Comment: @z5ottu I do not believe `HTTPoison` would transform the body in any case.

Comment: As I know `inspect` in `Logger.info` cannot convert anything back to the input argument (just for pretty printing in this case) Where do you face the problem? In the line of `Logger.info` or after `Jason.decode!` line?

Answer (score 1):

To eliminate whether or not HTTPoison is really deduping or not, you can use elixir to get the raw response back first:

```
defmodule Testmodule.HttpClient do
  def send_request(request, callback_host, callback_port) when is_integer(callback_port) do

    # Convert to charlist, as that's what the erlang function is expecting.
    some_host_in_net = callback_host |> String.to_charlist

    {:ok, socket} =
      :gen_tcp.connect(some_host_in_net, callback_port, [:binary, packet: :raw, active: false])

    :ok = :gen_tcp.send(socket, request)

    # Check response status
    case :gen_tcp.recv(socket, 0) do
      {:ok, response} -> :ok = :gen_tcp.close(socket)
        response
      {:error, :closed} -> IO.puts "Something went wrong."
    end

  end
end
```

Define your test request with:

```
def request_pool do
    """
    GET /getScoreData HTTP/1.1
    Host: localhost
    User-Agent: ExampleBrowser/1.0
    Accept: */*

    messagebody here
    """
  end
```

And finally, you can use Elixir/Erlang to call your endpoint:

```
Testmodule.HttpClient.send_request(request, "127.0.0.1", 8080)
```

This *should* get you what you're seeing in the browser, at which point you can parse it however your heart desires.

But as soon as you try to convert it using Poison.decode, keep in mind that it likely will dedupe your data, as it might treat duplicated keys as updates to the values, rather than allowing duplicate keys to exist in a map.